# call function in pushbutton and parameter

Tags: python, parameters, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

hi i wrote a python program in qt i want to call a function in pushbutton but its not work

my code is:

i write this code in pycharm and run this code but its not work 
i tested it in idle , vs , other environment but this is not work. when i use jcopy function to pushbutton event its work and its copy lineEdit text to lineEdit_2 text but when i want to use the jtrans function for translate the text of lineEdit and and copy result to lineEdit2 program is not work. in pycharm and vs  , idle dont sent any error but not work,so i write the same consol program that run in terminal that run currectly

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from googletrans import Translator
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(598, 456)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 201, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 220, 131, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 220, 201, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 220, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 551, 131))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 541, 141))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 598, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.jtrans)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Input Text:"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "persian"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "english"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "arabic"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "danish"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "dutch"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "output Text:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "translate"))

    # def jcopy(self):
    # t1=self.lineEdit.text()
    # self.lineEdit_2.setText(t1)

    def jtrans(self, translator=None):
        srcString = self.lineEdit.text()
        srcLang = translator.detect(srcString)
        dstLang = self.comboBox.currentText()
        translated = translator.translate(srcString, src=srcLang, dest=dstLang)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(translated.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

jcopy function only is a fuction that i know the pushbutton run the code

the problem is in sippet code:

```
 def jtrans(self, translator=None):
        srcString = self.lineEdit.text()
        srcLang = translator.detect(srcString)
        dstLang = self.comboBox.currentText()
        translated = translator.translate(srcString, src=srcLang, dest=dstLang)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(translated.text)
```

---

anybody can solve this problem
tnx

Answer (score 0):

You have a trivial error: Why do you set object `translator` to `def jtrans(self, translator=None):`? Do you think object `translator` was magically created? Well, no. If the error message is checked:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 74, in jtrans
    srcLang = translator.detect(srcString)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'detect'
```

It is understandable that it is not magically created, but X takes the value of what the default clicked signal sends: a boolean.

<sub>Before proposing the PyQt solution, I recommend not modifying the code generated by Qt Designer, so you will have to use pyuic and regenerate the file, I will assume that the generated file is called gui.py.</sub>

Keep in mind that the translation process is very time consuming so it could crash the GUI so you will have to run it in another thread. Another problem in your code is that the `detect` method does not return the language but an object of the `Detected` class that has the language information.

Considering the above, the solution is:

**main.py**

```py
import sys
import threading


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from googletrans import Translator

from gui import Ui_MainWindow


class WorkerTranslator(QtCore.QObject):
    translateSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def translate(self, text, dst_lang):
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._translate, args=(text, dst_lang), daemon=True
        ).start()

    def _translate(self, text, dst_lang):
        translator = Translator()
        src_lang = translator.detect(text).lang
        translated = translator.translate(text, src=src_lang, dest=dst_lang)
        self.translateSignal.emit(translated.text)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.translate)

        self.translator = WorkerTranslator()
        self.translator.translateSignal.connect(self.lineEdit_2.setText)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def translate(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        dst_lang = self.comboBox.currentText()
        self.translator.translate(text, dst_lang)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
├── gui.py
└── main.py
```